# exclude test.com from proxy list in ssh config file

Tags: ssh, proxy

I am ssh to all servers through proxy by adding below to my ssh config

```
Host * 
ProxyCommand nc -x 'someProxy.com' %h %p
```

How can I exclude `test.com` from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the match command and the negation operator:

```
Match Host *,!test.com
ProxyCommand nc -x 'someProxy.com' %h %p
```

source: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5